# deb package are not able to install in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 11.10, package-management, deb

I can install every deb package in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, but none of them can be install in Ubuntu 10.10. In Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, just simply double click on the deb package icon, and then click on "install package" in the gdebi-gtk window. But in Ubuntu 11.10, double click on deb package, waiting for a **long long** time, and finally the "software center" says that "i386 error"!!!!! What's wrong!

Comment: did you upgrade or clean install ? Did you use same architecture for installation i.e. amd64 or i386 ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have selected a wrong distribution as 64bit instead of 32bit.If your system is 64bit and you installed the same iso, then try to download and install .deb package for 64bit.